# LIBRARY_PATH,LD_LIBRARY_PATH empty - Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: environment-variables, libraries, paths

I have been using my machine with no issues, but when I want to add my custom path to default lookup paths for libraries I am not able to because LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set (empty). So I copy my library to usr/local/lib and it works.

Now my question is not about updating LD_LIBRARY_PATH to contain my custom built lib path, but why is that default macro value empty and how does the linker know (usr/local/lib, etc) libraries path if that variable is empty.  LD_LIBRARY_PATH is optional is it? The linker checks only etc/ld.so.conf and then LD_LIBRARY_PATH as additional step? If I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then will that override etc/ld.so.conf paths?

Comment: The ld.so manual page should answer most of your questions I think (`man 8 ld.so`)

Comment: Yes, I got the answer from the man page. Thanks. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is additional path specification on top of but has higher lookup priority than etc/ld.so.conf...